# Connecting Log4J viewer (chainsaw) to a MySql database

Tags: java, log4j, log4net, log4net-configuration

I want to use log4j viewer (Chainsaw) to read error logs logged in a MySql database by log4j. I am a bit struggling as the documentation is really sparse.

[strike]Here is my tentative .xml config for Chainsaw:[/strike]
Here is my new .xml config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration >
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="true">
  <plugin name="CustomDBReceiver" class="org.apache.log4j.db.CustomSQLDBReceiver">
     <connectionSource class="org.apache.log4j.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
       <param name="password" value="my_pwd"/>
       <param name="user" value="my_uid"/>
       <param name="driverClass" value="org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"/>
       <param name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://<my_host>:<my_host_port>/<my_database>"/>
  </connectionSource>
      <param name="refreshMillis" value="1000"/>
  <param name="sql" value='select ID as ID, Logger as LOGGER, Date as TIMESTAMP, Level as LEVEL, Thread as THREAD, Message as MESSAGE, Exception as EXCEPTION, DestID as DESTID, IPAddress as IP, Stacktrace as STACKTRACE from errorlogs'/>
  <param name="IDField" value="ID"/>
  </plugin>
  <root>
    <level value="debug"/>
  </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

It tells me that:

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://<my_host>:<my_host_port>/<my_database>
```

I have downloaded the DBReceiver extension (log4j-db-1.3alpha-7) and put it in my .chainsaw/plugins directory. I also put "mysql-connector-java-5.1.16-bin" in the .chainsaw directory just to be sure, since it seemed like it was the cause of the problem. However, it did not fix it.

Does any of you guys have know how to connect Chainsaw to a MySql database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And more info on how to use jars that aren't distributed with Chainsaw:

http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/distributionnotes.html

By the way, you may want to try the latest developer snapshot of Chainsaw, available here:

http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy

Lots of new features...

Scott

Comment: Thanks! I downloaded the latest version and I am glad that there are exemples of configuration files. However, I have a "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql" error when I try to fetch data from my database. I edited my post, if you don't mind to take an other look at it :)

Comment: Looks like I didn't put my "mysql-connector-java-5.1.16-bin" in the right place. I put it in my java/jre/lib/ext path and it stopped complaining. However, it tells me that "java.sql.SQLException: Column 'NDC' not found", when running my request. Are we required to have a NDC column in our database?

Comment: The JavaDoc for CustomSQLDBReceiver says to define columns in the SQL statement for 'LOGGER, TIMESTAMP, LEVEL, THREAD, MESSAGE, NDC, MDC, CLASS, METHOD, FILE, LINE, PROPERTIES, THROWABLE' and if you don't have one or more of those columns, just add '' as NDC to your SQL statement, so that an empty string will be in the 'result set' even though you don't have that column in your database.

Comment: Also, you should be able to put your JDBC jar in $USERHOME$/.chainsaw/plugins.  There is a checkbox in app-wide preferences to remove the securitymanager - you should only have to do that if you are using WebStart and adding jars to the plugins folder, but check that box, restart and see if that resolves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to configure [Chainsaw 2.1](http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy) to read Logback logs saved using [DBAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/db/DBAppender.html).

1. Do not download any plugins
2. Download the SQL driver (eg, `mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar`) and save it to `<chainsaw>\repo`.
3. Edit the startup script to add the jar to the classpath. Eg, in `chainsaw.bat` use:

   > set CLASSPATH="%BASEDIR%"\etc;"%REPO%"\log4j\apache-log4j-extras\1.1\apache-log4j-extras-1.1.jar;"%REPO%"\log4j\log4j\1.2.16\log4j-1.2.16.jar;"%REPO%"\javax\jmdns\jmdns\3.4.1\jmdns-3.4.1.jar;"%REPO%"\xstream\xstream\1.1.2\xstream-1.1.2.jar;"%REPO%"\commons-vfs\commons-vfs\1.0\commons-vfs-1.0.jar;"%REPO%"\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;"%REPO%"\com\jcraft\jsch\0.1.42\jsch-0.1.42.jar;"%REPO%"\log4j\apache-chainsaw\2.1.0-SNAPSHOT\apache-chainsaw-2.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;**"%REPO%"\mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar**
4. At startup choose "Use a Chainsaw config file"

Here is a Logback DBAppender-compatible configuration file:

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <plugin name="Logs" class="org.apache.log4j.db.CustomSQLDBReceiver">
        <param name="sql" 
               value="
                    SELECT 
                        logger_name AS 'LOGGER', 
                        from_unixtime (timestmp/1000) AS 'TIMESTAMP', 
                        level_string AS 'LEVEL', 
                        thread_name AS 'THREAD', 
                        formatted_message AS 'MESSAGE', 
                        (SELECT CONCAT('{{', group_concat(CONCAT(mapped_key, ',', mapped_value) SEPARATOR ','), '}}')
                            FROM logging_event_property
                            WHERE logging_event.event_id = logging_event_property.event_id 
                            GROUP BY logging_event_property.event_id) AS 'NDC', 
                        '' AS 'MDC',
                        caller_class AS 'CLASS', 
                        caller_method AS 'METHOD', 
                        caller_filename AS 'FILE', 
                        caller_line AS 'LINE',
                        CONCAT('{{application,test,hostname,', (SELECT mapped_value FROM logging_event_property WHERE logging_event.event_id = logging_event_property.event_id AND mapped_key = 'HOSTNAME'), ',log4jid,', event_id,'}}') AS 'PROPERTIES',
                        IFNULL((SELECT group_concat(trace_line ORDER BY i ASC SEPARATOR '\n')
                            FROM logging_event_exception 
                            WHERE logging_event.event_id = logging_event_exception.event_id 
                            GROUP BY logging_event_exception.event_id),'') AS 'THROWABLE'
                    FROM logging_event
                    WHERE 1=1"/>
        <connectionSource class="org.apache.log4j.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
            <param name="driverClass" value="<driver, eg com.mysql.jdbc.Driver>"/>
            <param name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://<url>/<schema>"/>
            <param name="user" value="<user>"/>
            <param name="password" value="<password>"/>
        </connectionSource>
        <param name="IDField" value="event_id"/>
        <param name="refreshMillis" value="3000"/>
    </plugin>

    <root>
        <level value="debug"/>
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

The select-in-select and the `where 1=1` are there to work around the CustomSQLDBReceiver's behavior of clumsily concatenating a `WHERE event_id > -1` or an `AND event_id > -1` at the end of the SQL expression. ([See lines 306-313.](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4j/companions/extras/tags/apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/receivers/db/CustomSQLDBReceiver.java?view=markup))

The documentation for `CustomSQLDBReceiver` is in [its javadoc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/receivers/db/CustomSQLDBReceiver.html).

For Logback-Access (on EC2 with an ELB) I use:

```
<plugin name="Access-Logs" class="org.apache.log4j.db.CustomSQLDBReceiver">
    <param name="sql" 
           value="
                SELECT 
                    REPLACE (requestURI, '/', '.') AS 'LOGGER', 
                    from_unixtime (timestmp/1000) AS 'TIMESTAMP', 
                    'INFO' AS 'LEVEL', 
                    IFNULL((SELECT header_value FROM access_event_header WHERE access_event.event_id = access_event_header.event_id AND header_key = 'x-forwarded-for'),'') AS 'THREAD', 
                    requestURL AS 'MESSAGE', 
                    '' AS 'NDC', 
                    '' AS 'MDC',
                    '' AS 'CLASS', 
                    '' AS 'METHOD', 
                    '' AS 'FILE', 
                    '' AS 'LINE', 
                    CONCAT('{{application,test,hostname,access,log4jid,', event_id,'}}')  AS 'PROPERTIES',
                    (SELECT group_concat(concat(header_key, ': ', header_value) SEPARATOR '\n')
                        FROM access_event_header
                        WHERE access_event.event_id = access_event_header.event_id 
                        GROUP BY access_event_header.event_id) AS 'THROWABLE'
                FROM access_event
                WHERE (SELECT header_value 
                        FROM access_event_header 
                        WHERE access_event.event_id = access_event_header.event_id AND header_key = 'user-agent')
                    != 'ELB-HealthChecker/1.0'"/>
    <connectionSource class="org.apache.log4j.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
        <param name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <param name="url" value=""/>
        <param name="user" value=""/>
        <param name="password" value=""/>
    </connectionSource>
    <param name="IDField" value="access_event.event_id"/>
    <param name="refreshMillis" value="3000"/>
</plugin>
```